# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, django-views, django-middleware

I am making an app of login form but when I am running my app and click on login button the following error will occur

**Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.**

the code of view.py is as:

```
from django.template import  loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from registration.models import Registration
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def view_login(request,registration_id):
   t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html') 
   try:
         registration=Registration.objects.get(pk=registration_id)
   except Registration.DoesNotExist:
         return render_to_response("login.html",{"registration_id":registration_id})

def home(request,registration_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
      username = request.POST.get('user_name')
      password = request.POST.get('password')
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
          login(request, user)
        # success
          return render('registration/main_page.html',{'registration_id':registration_id},context_instance=RequestContext(user))
        else:
         #user was not active
           return redirect('q/',context_instance=RequestContext(user))
      else:
        # not a valid user
           return redirect('q/',context_instance=RequestContext(user))
    else:
       # URL was accessed directly
           return redirect('q/',context_instance=RequestContext(user))
```

Comment: I was getting this error with django-allauth and didn't think the module had an issue. I later found out old code in my base.html file was breaking the form. This may help someone as none the answers here were relevant to me. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28488 is where I found out that some broken unrelated code could be the cause.

Comment: I've just had this csrf issue, and it was related to ezoic javascript I'd just added (ezoic being the ad company). Very hard to realise why it was an issue, but luckily it was the only change I'd made, so easy to revert.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add `{% csrf_token %}` in your form

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

like that :

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <anything_else>
</form>
```

Also, you have to use RequestContext(request) everytime you use `render_to_response` :

```
return render_to_response("login.html",
    {"registration_id":registration_id},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And you have to import authenticate and login :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
```

Comment: in **home.html** or **login.html** or **both**

Comment: It depend, where is your form ?

Comment: ok, I added it but still getting the error.  Wheather I have to import somethong ???

Comment: I think it is incorrect . `return render('registration/main_page.html',{'registration_id':registration_id},context_instance=RequestContext(user))`
**Right ????**

Comment: in the doc is sayd you need to add django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in your middleware

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15944/discussion-between-neeraj-and-bluemagma)

Answer (score 19):

For those who are using `Django==4.*` or above, there must be an additional field in `settings.py` called `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=[]` and add your domain here, Problem solved.

Check this [latest release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0).

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem for me. How does one keep up on version changes like this, do you just make a point of reading release notes whenever they are released? Even with DEBUG=True the error wasn't at all helpful for me, it was pure luck I came across your answer.

Answer (score 13):

In **Django ≥ 4** it is now necessary to specify **CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS** in **settings.py**

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://your-domain.com', 'https://www.your-domain.com']
```

See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0)

Comment: No it's not. "Configuring it *may* now be required" [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes)

Answer (score 3):

Just comment 
`'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`

in your **settings.py**, which works for me:

```
//settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**THIS MAY HAVE SECURITY FLAWS UNLESS YOU SOMEHOW MANAGE CSRF IN ANOTHER WAY, AND IS NOT RECOMMENDED, AS YOU WILL BE SUSCEPTIABLE TO CSRF ATTACKS**

Comment: I'd never do that, it means that you expose your website to Cross Site Request Forgery attacks

Comment: It is really not a answer. a way for hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem while using the book "The Definitive Guide to Django" wherein version 1.1 is used. The book does not address the need for csrf_token verification that is mandated in later versions.

To fix this issue, add:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```

to the views.py file and this added argument for the render_to_response function:

```
context_instance = RequestContext(request)
```

Be sure to add `{% csrf_token %}` within the `<form>` tags in the template

Answer (score 0):

When you have "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted" you can alternatively do:

**option (2)** (not preferred)

import:

```
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
```

add to context:

```
context = {}
context.update(csrf(request))
```

return:

-Django > 1.9 has "context" instead of "context_instance"

```
return render_to_response("login.html",
    {"registration_id":registration_id},
    context=context)
```

**option (3)** (preferred)

import:

-instead of importing "render_to_response" import "render"

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

return:

```
return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

Apparently option 3 is preferable, because "render" is shorter than "render_to_response", especially if you need to import and add stuff. I could imagine option 2 keeps a leaner context dict, but this seems trivial (?).

For clarity:

Both solutions still need the {% csrf_token %} in your html form as mentioned above. And **never** turn off or comment the csrf middelware.

sources:

[old Django 1.9 docs on RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

[Django 2 docs on the csrf processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-csrf)

[source explaining render is enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408947/python-render-with-csrf-protection)

Answer (score 0):

While it is probably not the OP's problem, I discovered that adding the verfication code from ezoic actually messed up my CSRF process. Adding the code destroyed my sites login process and probably other forms as well.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question; it is better suited as a comment. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
method: 'POST',
headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              "X-CSRFToken": $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
         },

{% csrf_token %} => add this inside header tag in html
```