# Python - render with csrf protection

Tags: python, django, csrf

I've read several posts about csrf protection in Django, including [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) , but I'm still quite confused in how to use it correctly.

The clearest part is the HTML one, but the Python's one is kinda confusing.

### HTML

`{% csrf_token %}` inside the form

### Python

```
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
```

You need it in every form when displaying and requesting the information, don't you?

---

Then, how do you include this csrf protection in the `return render()`? Is this correct?

`return render(request,'index.html',{'var':var_value})`

or should I include the `c` somewhere like in the [Python documentation example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it) (`return render_to_response("a_template.html", c)`). Or, if it's correct, is it included in the `request` var?

---

And, when not needing to use csrf because I don't have any form. Would this be the right form to return values to a template?

`return render(request,'index.html',{'var':var_value})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of using the `render` shortcut is that it then runs all the context processors automatically. Context processors are useful little functions that add various things to the template context every time a template is rendered. And there is a built-in context processor that already adds the CSRF token for you. So, if you use `render`, there is nothing more to do other than to output the token in the template.

Comment: So, `c = {}    c.update(csrf(request))` would only be used in case there was not a `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`, right?

Comment: No, that's a different thing: it's `django.core.context_processors.csrf` in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. The context processor adds the token to the context, and the middleware is responsible for the verification on POST.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember Django has its own middleware for the csrf protection that handles everthing transparently for you. Just include the `{% csrf_token %}` inside you forms. CSRF token is mandatory for POST requests (except you use the @csrf_exempt decorator). So a form would be:

```
<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
 your input fields and submit button...
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware" listed in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES variable in the settings file you should be to just have {% csrf_token %} in your templates.

There's a lot more useful info in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/