# Django: "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." in Docker Production

Tags: python, django, django-admin, csrf, django-csrf

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to login into Django Admin or Whenever I try to signup in my Django application.

I am using Production in Docker and serving site with `http`.
Whatever I know, this problem is arises because of serving it over `http` instead of `https`.

Here is my production settings.py:

```
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 518400
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = env.bool('DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS', default=True)
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = env.bool('DJANGO_SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF', default=True)
# SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool('DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT', default=False)
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
```

I know I have to make some changes into this setting to make it work, but I don't know which one.

Comment: Came accross this issue too and I hade to remove all the security settings that i  didnt know the way they work, was using the default cookiecutter-django settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your error message includes a line like :

```
  Origin checking failed - http://my.web.site.com does not match any trusted origins.
```

If that's the case, your problem is probably that your django code running inside Docker sees a request as coming from a different site (the one outside Docker) and complains about it.

Proper solution is to trust your site. Add a line like this one to your `settings.py` :

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://my.web.site.com',
]
```

See Django documentation for more details: [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/)

Answer (score -1):

Try the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174040/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted):

You need to add {% csrf_token %} in your form

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/

like that :

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <anything_else>
</form>
```

Also, you have to use RequestContext(request) everytime you use render_to_response :

```
return render_to_response("login.html",
    {"registration_id":registration_id},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And you have to import authenticate and login :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
```

Comment: My problem is not with {% csrf_token %}, my site is working well over `https` but this problem is only occurring when I serve it using `http`