# Run django api from postman: CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django, curl

I'm trying to run an api using `postman`. My application is developed in `django 1.11.6` using `python 3.5`.

My app is installed on an `ubuntu` server. I have no login mechanism to create a `csrf` token.

These are the steps that I follow:

1. Click on "import" tab on the upper left side.
2. Select the Raw Text option and paste my `cURL` command.
3. Hit import and I have the command in your Postman builder
4. Press send button.

My `curl` command is:

```
curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -X POST  https://127.0.0.1/users/:register/ -d "id=111&firstname=zinonas&yearofbirth=2007&lastname=Antoniou&othernames="
```

The error I get is `Forbidden (403) - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`.

When I run the `curl command` via `cygwin`, it's working properly.

This is the view function that I'm using:

```
class ApiUserRegister(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = RegisterUserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        # Check format and unique constraint
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.data

        if User.objects.filter(id=data['id']).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(id=data['id'])
            is_new = "false"
            resp_status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        else:
            user = User.objects.create(id=data['id'],
                                       firstname=data['firstname'],
                                       yearofbirth=data['yearofbirth'],
                                       lastname=data['lastname'],
                                       othernames=data['othernames'])
            user.save()
            is_new = "true"
            resp_status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        resp = {"user": serializer.get_serialized(user),
                "isnew": is_new}
        return Response(resp, status=resp_status)
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: where is the view that you are trying to get?

Comment: @mohammedqudah It's a view to register a new user. I've added it to my question.

Comment: In your curl command, your url does not look good as it contains `:`.

Comment: @aquaman Yes, I want to have this character in my api.

Comment: Also if you are requesting `https` you should use something like `curl -k ...`

Comment: is it remote api or you have access to settings file of api ?

Comment: It's located in a server but I do have access to `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
class ApiUserRegister(APIView):
permission_classes = ()
serializer_class = RegisterUserSerializer

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
```

Comment: Refer this.                                                                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174040/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted

Comment: I'm not using any template.

Answer (score 7):

To make AJAX requests, you need to include CSRF token in the HTTP header, as [described in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#ajax).

1st option

[image]

2nd option
[image]

Comment: I'm not using `jQuery`. I created an API to using via `android' app.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: 1. get csrftoken cookie with safe GET query (view can use ensure_csrf_cookie decorator) 2. use csrftoken in new POST query

Comment: The answer does not address Postman, which is a key part of the question.

Comment: This is about rest API. So, why bother about CSRF token?

Comment: @MohammedShareefC yes, for android app we don't need CSRF, but https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

simple just make sure to put as_view()

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sign_up', views.SignUp.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
```

Add "@csrf_protect, @csrf_exempt" Before the method

Answer (score 0):

update your class to be like this

```
from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin
class your_class(CsrfExemptMixin, ......yours_here)
   def post(...):
       [....]
```

this will tell django to allow requests without csrf

Comment: Using this I get `name 'csrf_exempt' is not defined` error.

Comment: I get error `'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'`.In `urls.py` I have this line: `url(r':register/$', views.ApiUserRegister.as_view(), name='register-user')`

Comment: No I get the error `The keyword argument "name" must be the name of a method of the decorated class: <class 'users.views.ApiUserRegister'>. Got '' instead`

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I set `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="post")` and now I get once again `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Comment: Is `braces` a module that I can install using `pip3`?

Comment: pip install django-braces

Comment: Still no luck `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Comment: csrfExpemntMixin should be the first then ApiView

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: try adding *authentication_classes = []* to the class

Answer (score 0):

Django sets csrftoken cookie on login. After logging in, we can see the csrf token from cookies in the Postman. (see image)
[CSRFtoken from cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WR3L.png)

We can grab this token and set it in headers manually.
But this token has to be manually changed when it expires. This process becomes tedious to do it on an expiration basis.

Instead, we can use Postman scripting feature to extract the token from the cookie and set it to an environment variable. In Test section of the postman, add these lines.

```
var xsrfCookie = postman.getResponseCookie("csrftoken"); postman.setEnvironmentVariable('csrftoken', xsrfCookie.value);
```

This extracts csrf token and sets it to an environment variable called csrftoken in the current environment.
Now in our requests, we can use this variable to set the header.(see image)
[Set {{csrftoken}} in your header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vs4o.png)

When the token expires, we just need to log in again and csrf token gets updated automatically.

Thanks to [@chillaranand from hackernoon.com](https://hackernoon.com/automatically-set-csrf-token-in-postman-django-tips-c9ec8eb9eb5b) to original post

Answer (score -1):

In urls file, try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^your_uri/', views.YourView.as_view()),
]
```

this will tell django to allow requests without csrf