# "Forbidden 403 - CSRF verification failed" when using .submit(function) in Django form

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I've been developing in application with Django that has a bunch of forms, each one in a different page. In one of the first views, I just ask the user a simple information, that is POST sent to Python and used to some formulas. The code I used to do so is show below, and it runs smoothly:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
</head>

{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/content/bootstrap.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/content/custom.css' %}">

<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery.validate.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/custom.js' %}"></script>

{% if error == 404 %}
<label>Who are you? Go away!</label>
<br>
{% endif %}
Welcome! Give me your data!
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="post" id="myPrettyForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#q").mask("00000000000");

</script>
</html>
```

As I said, this code runs nicely. However, I want to add a function, in which, once I click the "submit", the `q` input field is disabled. To do so, I tried adding this piece of code to the script above:

```
$("#myPrettyForm").submit(function () {
    $("#myPrettyForm:input").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

However, when I add this snippet to my code, everytime I try to submit my form, I receive a "**Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.**" error. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174040/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted), this error is commonly related to the form not having the `{% csrf_token %}` element. However, my form already has this element.

So what am I doing wrong in here? And if I'm using the wrong method to prevent my user to write in the inputs after the form is submitted, which other method could
I use?

Comment: You may be changing things before the submit.
csrf is a token that generates a random number every time form is generated (to stop fake data). You may need to change **when** you modify the form. See if you can modify a few seconds after submit. Or do it through backend.

Or as above, maybe you arnt sending the token anymore

Comment: try disabling by id `q` in jquery function maybe you are disabling csrf hidden input as well by `input` class that is expected at server side `request.POST`

Comment: @Ahtisham what do you mean?

Comment: @Ahtisham, so far I didn't need ajax in this form. As I said, when there isn't the JavaScript snippet, it works fine

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari, you are right! I just changed to disable just `q` and it worked out! However, now my view isn't receiving the data in `q`... Any idea on how to disable the field, but keep the data "sendable"?

Comment: try setting it readonly `$("#fieldName").attr('readonly','readonly');`

Comment: Works like a charm! Though I used a very similar version of what you suggested, `$("#fieldId").prop("readonly", true);` Thank you very much!

Comment: You disabled *all* inputs, including the hidden one that contains the CSRF token. You should only disable the `q` input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't notice it ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` is a dictionary with form data. 
Disabling input class will make all input including csrf_token as disabled. 
Right way is to reference the component by id and keeping the component as "readonly" like you did `$("#fieldId").prop("readonly", true);`