# Django admin doest work on production. Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with admin login on Production.
Everything works fine on local

I use httpS
I've already cleaned my browser cache for several times. It doesn't help

Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['tibrains.com']

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://www.tibrains.com',
    'https://www.tibrains.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/',
    'tibrains.com',
    'www.tibrains.com'
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['tibrains.com', 
'https://www.tibrains.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/',
'https://www.tibrains.com/admin/', ]
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.tibrains.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "tibrains.com"
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Nginx

```
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: Is this helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12174091/9814037 If so let me know I'll add as answer to get credits.