# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. django error

Tags: python, django, csrf

I want to post a form with HTML

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    // some inputs
</form>
```

views.py

```
def request_create(request):
    context = {}
    return render(
      request, template_name="requestz/request_form.html", context=context
    )
```

My middlewares are these

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

When I try to post a form, it is showing the following error

```
Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

When I go back from error and submit the form again it works!

Comment: Cab you share your view and any `CSRF_*` settings you may have in your settings.py

Comment: I don't have any CSRF settings @IainShelvington

Comment: Can you add your view to the question?

Comment: It doesn't matter the view, I'm debugging, and before executing the views.py it shows the errorr. Also to inform you, when I go back and click the submit button again it works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174040/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted)

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me!

Comment: @maca2.0 So you are not gonna share views.py with us. You are not gonna let us check if you are using RequestContext and importing correct libraries.

Comment: are you importing render() from django.shortcuts?

Comment: Yes, I'm importing from there